# UDP bad checksum errors

Tags: kvm, dpdk

UDP checksum cannot be computed by Hardware virtualization( SRIOV PCI passthrough).UDP bad checksum errors are observed  in the tcpdump(pcap) collected after host on the Service router when the UDP checksum computation is Hardware offloaded.

Comment: UDP checksum is set  to 0  and Hardware offloading is disabled to prevent the UDP checksum errors.Is this the only way out?Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compute the checksum in software using `rte_ipv4_phdr_cksum()` and `rte_ipv4_udptcp_cksum()`. Please note that calculating UDP checksum might slow down the performance of your application.

Please note, [IPv4 UPD checksum is optional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#IPv4_Pseudo_Header), so setting it to zero is perfectly fine and according to the standards.

Please also note, the [Stack Overflow mission](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) is "to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming". If the answer for your question is correct, please mark so. If not, please provide a correct answer, i.e. self-answer your question.